# How to centre my CSS menu?

Tags: css

First posted working code gets awarded the answer...

Here's a simple web-page with a CSS drop-down menu

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Center menu test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css_menu.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="menu">
  <ul><li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li></ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Menu with items</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html#anchor_1">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="home.html#anchor_2">two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the corresponding CSS :

```
.menu {margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; padding:0; margin:8px; color: #000000; width:100%; border:1px;  clear:both;} 

/*Color navigation bar normal mode*/
.menu a, 
.menu a:visited {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;color: #000000;background-color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;}
.menu ul {list-style-type:none;padding:0; margin:0;}
.menu ul li {float:left; position:relative; z-index:auto !important /*Non-IE6*/; z-index:1000 /*IE6*/; margin-right: 4px; border:solid 1px #004080; }
.menu ul li a {color: #000000;background: #FFFFFF;float:none !important /*Non-IE6*/; float:left /*IE-6*/; display:block; height:30px; line-height:30px; padding:0 10px 0 10px; text-decoration:none; }
.menu ul li ul {display:none; border:none;color: #000000; background: #FFFFFF;}
.menu ul li:hover a {background-color:#d7f1ff; text-decoration:none; color:#000000;}     
.menu ul li:hover ul {display:block;  position:absolute; z-index:999; top:29px; margin-top:1px; left:0;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {display:block; width:12em; height:auto; line-height:1.3em; margin-left:-1px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; border-left:solid 1px #004080; border-bottom: solid 1px #004080; background-color:#FFFFFF;  color:#000000;} 
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {background-color:#d7f1ff; text-decoration:none;color:#000000;} 
.menu table {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border-collapse:collapse;color: #000000;background: #FFFFFF;}
.menu ul li a:hover {background-color:#d7f1ff; text-decoration:none;color:#000000;} 
.menu ul li a:hover ul {display:block; width:12em; position:absolute; z-index:999; top:29px; left:0; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a {display:block; width:12em; height:1px; line-height:1.3em; padding:4px 16px 4px 16px; border-left:solid 1px #004080; border-bottom: solid 1px #004080; background-color:#FFFFFF;  color:#000000;} 
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover {background-color:#d7f1ff; text-decoration:none;color:#000000;}
```

Why isn't the menu centered on the page?

Comment: Did you try adding a div around the menu, making it 100% width and setting position: relative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its width is `100%`, so it is centered, but not centred visibly (how can you center something that takes up 100% of the width?).

It may be easier to understand by looking at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pjQVd/).

[Thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405015/thirtydot) also points out that `margin: 8px` is clobbering your previous setting of `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

#### Update

[Here it is, working](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/sLAcF/).

I would recommend changing your markup - having each in a separate `ul` is confusing.

Comment: then how can I center it visibly?

Comment: Add a div around it with width 100%

Comment: Also see `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;` and `margin:8px;` on `.menu`. Surely wrong.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions Can you explicitly set its width?

Comment: @thirtydot Missed that first time, have made an edit. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @Alex. No, sorry I cannot. Basically, the entire content of the page is centered, so it looks strange when the menu is left-aligned.

Comment: @thirtydot, +1 thanks. But, rather than says what's wrong, can you tell me what would be right? First posted working code gets awarded the answer.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions You probably want to center the `li` children then. Change them from `float: left` to `display: inline-block`. Google `inline-block` for the caveats. Then set `.menu ul { text-align: center }`. You may then need to do `text-align: left` on the `li` to reset them to left aligned.

Comment: @LeonixSolutions: What browsers do you care about? (Do you care about IE6 or IE7?)

Comment: @alex: Was thinking the exact same thing.

Comment: @Dave L I'm not sure if that will fix it.

Comment: @thirtydot Google `display: inline-block` and check out the caveats. I think I have missed some IE specific thing to make it work (maybe it is because they are `ul`, and not `li`).

Comment: @alex: You can significantly improve the IE7 experience simply by adding `zoom: 1` to `.menu ul`. http://fiddle.jshell.net/sLAcF/1/show/light/

Comment: @thirtydot Ah yeah, that is what I forgot! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin:auto` to center an element.

IE is a bit picky with centering elements, so do some tests. If it doesn't work in IE, set `text-align:center` to center the element's contents. Beware though, `text-align` is inherited as it cascades.

Comment: +1 I'll give it a try, but would much prefer soemone to post some working code as I am far from being a CSS guru

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
body{
  text-align:center;
}
.menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  width:750px; /*change width as needed*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use display:inline for li & margin:auto and text-align:center for Ul

```
.header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #231F20;
    clear: both;
    height: 20px;
}

.header ul {
    clear: both;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.header ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Here header is the div containing the menu ul & li